# In Python a tuple is immutable object but allows mutation of a contained list?

Tags: python

In Python:

```
>>> tup = (1,"a",[1,2,3])
>>> tup
(1, 'a', [1, 2, 3])
>>> tup[2][1] = "a"
>>> tup
(1, 'a', [1, 'a', 3])
```

From the above I could modify the list contents which is part of the tuple. Since tuple is immutable how is this possible?
Did I understood the immutable part in a wrong way?

Comment: Because a `list` is alway mutable.

Comment: You did not mutated tuple. Third element still contains reference to same list. List was changed, tuple technically was not.

Comment: Compare `[id(x) for x in tup]` before and after you modify the contained list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did understand the immutable part the wrong way. The tuple is indeed immutable, as you cannot change its list:

```
In [3]: tup[2] = []
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-02255d491606> in <module>()
----> 1 tup[2] = []

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

The **reference** to the list is immutable in that tuple. However, the list itself is mutable, and hence can be modified, as you already know.

In other words, your tuple, which is immutable, contains three elements:

- Integer 1
- string "a"
- A **reference** to a list.

You can imagine it as the adress of the list, if you know C. If you don't know anything about memory, you can see it as "the tuple knows **where** to find the list". But it doesn't contain the list itself.

Comment: Ok, I know C, I understood now that tuple stores the reference to the list (not the actual value which is my earlier understanding) which cannot be modified , but once you pick the reference(list),  the list values can be modified, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The tuple container is immutable, but the elements inside it may or may not be immutable.

The tuple in your example is indeed immutable, but it contains a **reference to a mutable list**.

> So in the end I am able to modify the tuple contents?

No, you can't make the tuple point to a different list, but you can change what's inside the list.

When you do `tup[2][1]="a"`, you didn't mutate the tuple, you mutated the list. The tuple still has the **same reference to the list** as it did before.

**Snippet to see that the references haven't changed:**

We can use [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id), which returns the identity of the object (which in CPython returns the address of the object in memory)

```
>>> tup = (1,"a",[1,2,3])
>>> tup
(1, 'a', [1, 2, 3])
>>> [id(x) for x in tup]
[36090200, 140119363921520, 140119362889416]
>>> tup[2][1] = 'a'
>>> tup
(1, 'a', [1, 'a', 3])
>>> [id(x) for x in tup]
[36090200, 140119363921520, 140119362889416]
```

Comment: Immutable means contents cannot be modified right? But here I am able to modify the contents of the tuple using a mutable container, So at the end I am able to modify the tuple contents?

Answer (score 0):

A tuple is immutable--it will always *contain the same objects*. If those objects are mutable, they might themselves be mutated, but the tuple will still contain that object.